# Celery task on_success handler has kwargs always empty

Tags: python-2.7, celery, celery-task, keyword-argument

**Celery version = 4.3.0**

All I want to do is be able to access the actual arguments to the celery task function (normal and keyword) inside the custom success handler of the task. I am able to properly print out the non-keyword arguments, but the keyword arguments are always empty.

Below is the code

*taskResultsHandler*

```
from celery import Task

class ActionOnCompletion(Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        print "inside success handler"
        print retval[0] # prints => ["results"]
        print retval[1].get('meta') # prints => this is meta
        print "task function args were"
        print args # prints => (<value_of_arg1 as passed while invoking the task>, <value_of_arg2 as passed while invoking the task>)
        print "keyword args"
        print type(kwargs) # prints => <type 'dict'>
        print kwargs # prints => {} I was expecting {"someKeyWordArg":"randommmm"} to be printed here !
        print kwargs.get('someKeyWordArg') # does not print anything

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print einfno
```

*actual task*

```
from celeryConfig.celeryApp import celapp
from celeryConfig.taskResultsHandler import ActionOnCompletion

@celapp.task(base=ActionOnCompletion)
def myTask(arg1, arg2, someKeyWordArg="randommmm"):
    print("starting my task")
    print someKeyWordArg
    time.sleep(5)
    return ["results"], {'meta':"this is meta"}
```

Can someone please help me understand what am I missing in the above and why am I able to get the non keyword args fine but an empty keyword arg ?

Now I have workarounds to get my job done, like using just args instead of kwargs in my task and accessing them in the *on_success*, but I am really interested in knowing what's going wrong in the above.

Answer (score 0):

Your task signature needs to change to `def on_success(self, retval, task_id, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: This still does not work. I tried and get the same empty dictionary. :(

Comment: @qre0ct did you succeed in solving this?

Comment: @MikhailSibirev nope. I went on to work without it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little confusing, but what's happening is celery is not recording kwargs because they are default - they're not *passed in* the way your args are (which are required, because they are positional). IOW, celery is not examining the method signature for default kwargs, it only records what was actually passed when calling `delay` (or `apply_async` etc).